# Generate pgp files during package

Tags: scala, sbt

As part of `sbt package`, I wish to also generate the `pgp` signatures for jar. Note that I do not intend to publish to any repository, but I just want to generate it locally. This can then be used by `sbt-pack` to generate a tar of application.

With `sbt-pgp`, it generates the pgp signature files with  `publishLocalSigned`. How do I generate during `package` (or any other task)

Answer (score 1):

[`signedArtifacts`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/blob/eaab8bd48358b7fe50dd2f3e91d41b139711db66/pgp-plugin/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/pgp/PgpKeys.scala#L41) seems to package and sign artifacts without publishing. Analysing its [definition](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/blob/209e33c3ddec54f0857081db33cba81feb1880de/pgp-plugin/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/pgp/PgpSettings.scala#L170) we see that [`packagedArtifacts`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/8af7a5acaef783b69d0f4c88d348ac3d90c753ad/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L390) and [`pgpSigner`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/blob/eaab8bd48358b7fe50dd2f3e91d41b139711db66/pgp-plugin/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/pgp/PgpKeys.scala#L13) are the main elements needed to sign a particular artifact:

```
signedArtifacts := {
  val artifacts = packagedArtifacts.value
  val r = pgpSigner.value
  ...
    artifacts flatMap {
      case (art, file) =>
        Seq(art                                                -> file,
            subExtension(art, art.extension + gpgExtension) -> r.sign(file, new File(file.getAbsolutePath + gpgExtension), s))
    }
  ...
```